# IndexError: Invalid rect index

Tags: python, index-error

```
#importing stuff

import pygame
from pygame.locals import QUIT

import random as ran


#defining variables

SNAKE_WIDTH = 50
SNAKE_HEIGHT = 50

FPS = 60

GREEN = (0, 128, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

SNAKE_HEAD_IMAGE = pygame.image.load('snake_head.png')
SNAKE_HEAD = pygame.transform.scale(SNAKE_HEAD_IMAGE, (SNAKE_WIDTH, SNAKE_HEIGHT))

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500
DIS = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake Race")

SPEED = 3


#functions



#draw function

def draw_screen(snake):
    DIS.fill(WHITE)
    DIS.blit(SNAKE_HEAD, (snake.x, snake.y))
    pygame.display.update()

#movement function
def snake_movement(snake, key_press):
    if key_press[pygame.K_LEFT] and snake.x - SPEED > 0:
        snake.x -= SPEED

    if key_press[pygame.K_RIGHT] and snake.x + SPEED < 500:
        snake.x += SPEED

#main game loop
def main():

    snake = pygame.Rect(250, 300, SNAKE_HEIGHT, SNAKE_WIDTH) 
    
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    game_running = True

    while game_running:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_running = False


        key_press = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        snake_movement(key_press, snake)
        draw_screen(snake)

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

so the problem I am having starts on line 42 of the program where I am trying to make it so that my snake head cant move beyond the border of the screen I am new to pygame and am following a pygame tutorial the error I am receiving is IndexError:

> Invalid rect index stemming from here if key_press[pygame.K_LEFT] and snake.x - SPEED > 0:

in my IDE it hasn't marked this code as a error and I don't see anything wrong with it

I tried doing a few google searches to see if I could find a similar issue or question being asked but I didn't find anything on my initial search if someone could at least tell me whats wrong with the code I would be greatly appreciative

Comment: You have accidentally swapped the arguments. It should be **`snake_movement(snake, key_press)`** instead of `snake_movement(key_press, snake)`

Comment: The error you're encountering is likely due to the fact that the snake rectangle's x attribute is being updated directly, causing its position to exceed the valid boundaries of the screen. To fix this issue, you should modify the snake's position using a separate variable that holds the snake's current x-coordinate.